# Is possible to make a tuple of types with optional template parameters in C++14?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I'm working in a simulator. This simulator receives as input 2 kind of models, behavioural, and structural.

A behavioural model, is some any class that provides a few required functions and requires a template parameter "TIME".

A structural model, is a set of models (behavioural or structural) and a list of interactions between them. A structural model, does not provide behaviour, and as such does not require the parameter for TIME.

Example of behavioural model:

```
template<typename TIME>
struct B {...};
```

Example of Structural model:

```
template<typename connections, typename Ms>
struct S {
    template<typename TIME>
    using models=typename Ms::template type<TIME>;
    ...
};
```

The main problem is the "models" here.
As it is listed there, every model gets a TIME template parameter, and I can get as many B models as I want. However, I cannot pass a S model to it.

My implementation of a models_tuple is the following

```
template<template<typename TIME> class... Ms>
struct models_tuple {
    template<typename T>
    using type=std::tuple<Ms<T>...>;
};
```

Is there any way that I can make the tuple receive both, classes with a Template parameter (Time) and others without it?
I'm using static_assert for validating that classes are covering the requirements of implementing the functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have a mix of template template parameters and template type parameters. But you can wrap the former into a type.

```
template<template<class> class B>
struct wrap {};
```

Then, add the time, but only if it's the wrapper for the first kind of types:

```
template<class W, class>
struct maybe_apply_time { using type = W; };

template<class T, template<class> class B> 
struct maybe_apply_time<wrap<B>, T> { using type = B<T>; };

template<class... Ms>
struct models_tuple {
    template<typename T>
    using type=std::tuple<typename maybe_apply_time<Ms, T>::type...>;
};
```

And uses it as `models_tuple<wrap<B>, S</*...*/> /*, etc. */>.`

Comment: `template<typename...> class B` should be the default form when it comes to template template parameters. This allows the user to have e.g. `wrap<std::vector>`.

Comment: @LucDanton It also allows you to do `wrap<std::pair>` and have it explode deep inside your machinery instead of at the point of use. Not convinced that it should be the default.

Comment: @LucDanton: And there is still `template <typename T> using default_vector = std::vector<T>;` and then `wrap<default_vector>` to allow regular `vector`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. the key for me is the first 2 lines. I tried to make wrappers using ellipsis, but it didn't work. The thing was that I assumed template type parameters could be used as template template parameters of "0 template parameters". Marking this as solution.